# python: howto open firefox (osx)

Tags: python, macos, firefox

I need to associate to a hyperlink the command to execute firefox.
Seeing as I can do it in a terminal, I used

```
 os.system("/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox"+' \"'+arg+'\" & 2> /dev/null')
```

but this doesnt work at all: I get a "Firefox is already running" window - while under Linux my url gets loaded in a new tab.

I tried the -remote switch, without effect

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remember to accept an answer to your question by clicking the check mark next to the one that helped you most. You should go back and do this for any old questions that have been answered, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`webbrowser`](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html)

Answer (score 4):

To be more specific, to choose Firefox, if it is not the standard browser on the OS:

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> controller = webbrowser.get('Firefox')
>>> controller.open('http://www.google.com')
True
```